# Regex: backtracking and optional quantifier

Tags: regex

I have some file names and I want to get the timestamp and optional sequence number out of it.

```
Log-20220408_212412_001.txt           
Log-20220408_212412.txt    
Log-20220408_2124.txt
```

I used

```
Log-(?<timestamp>[0-9_]+)(?<sequence>_[\d]{3})?.txt$
```

In C#, it works if I configure regex to search from "right to left".  But the "right to left" flag is not commonly supported. Is there any alternative way to do it? Thanks

Comment: The problem is `[0-9_]+` matches ALL numbers, since `_[\d]{3}` is optional.

Comment: It seems you just want to make `[0-9_]+` lazy. `Log-(?<timestamp>[0-9_]+?)(?<sequence>_\d{3})?.txt$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I need to make [0-9_]+ lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with an optional group:

```sh
^Log-(?<timestamp>\d+(?:_\d{4,})?)(?:_(?<sequence>\d{3}))?\.txt
```

[C# RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qreljQ/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `Log-`: Match `Log-`
- `(?<timestamp>\d+_(?:_\d{4,})?)`: Match and capture `digits_digits` in names group `timestamp` where part after `_` is optional.
- `(?:_(?<sequence>\d{3}))?`: Optional group that starts with `_` and matched and captures 3 digits in named group `sequence`
- `\.txt`: Match `.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I actually need to handle cases like Log-20220408_003.txt.  I realize that I need to make "[0-9_]+" lazy and it works. Log-(?<timestamp>[0-9_]+?)(?<sequence>_\d{3})?.txt

Comment: Hmm but that will also match `Log-______003.tx`

Comment: See updated answer that works without matching invalid `Log-______003.txt`